# Define image size with random image code?

Tags: javascript, html, elementor, image-size

At the moment I'm working with Elementor on Wordpress. What I'd like to do is have one of "modules" in Elementor filled with random images that also have each a different link to some page. I looked for a random image widget but those I found didn't provide a function to define a different link for each randomized image. So I decided to use the html widget on Elementor to use my own code. I'm not super skilled at this. So I have a code, the randomizing is working, so are the links but I don't know how to define a max. width for the images because they just fill the whole page with this code. My english isn't very good I hope someone might be able to help me and where to put something in the code to define the images size?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageUrls = [
       "IMAGE1“ 
     , "IMAGE2“
     , "IMAGE3“
  ];
 var imageLinks = [
       "LINK1“
      , "LINK2“
       , "LINK3“ 
  ];

  function getImageHtmlCode() {
    var dataIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageUrls.length);
    var img = '<a href=\"' + imageLinks[dataIndex] + '"><img src="';        
    img += imageUrls[dataIndex];
    img += '\" alt=\"\"/></a>';
    return img;
  }
  

</script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(getImageHtmlCode());
</script>
</body>
```